# Can anyone explain how this conditional expectation is calculated?

Tags: conditional-expectation

To get: $E[X|X\leq q]$. Why it is in the following form?
assuming X's pdf is $f(x)$.

$\frac{\int_{x\leq q}xf(x)dx}{\int_{x\leq q}f(x)dx}$

Answer (score 3):

The *conditional* pdf of $X$ *given* that $X \leq q$ is given by
$$f_{X\mid X \leq q}(x\mid X\leq q) = 
\begin{cases}\frac{f_X(x)}{P\{X \leq q\}}, & x \leq q,\\
0, &x > q.\end{cases}$$ Now, write $P\{X \leq q\}$ as an integral of the
*unconditional* pdf of $X$ and then substitute into the usual formula for the expectation of a continuous random variable:

$$E[X\mid X \leq q] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X\mid X \leq q}(x\mid X\leq q) \,\mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^q x \frac{f_{X}(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^q f_X(y)\, \mathrm dy}\,\mathrm dx$$